# string match between two dataframe with difference sizes and return matching index and value

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, match

I have 2 dataframes with different sizes that I'd like to compare & find the matching first occurrence.

The shorter dataframe has no duplicate values, the second one has multiple instances of the same values.

For each row value in the shorter dataframe (df1), I'd like to find the first instance of the matched string & return the index and the value of another column in the larger dataframe (df2).

```
df1 =  pd.DataFrame({'type':['Apple3','Pear28','Banana0','Lime46']})
```

```
df2 =  pd.DataFrame({'type':['Apple2','Apple3','Lime46','Apple3','Lime46','Pear28'],'color':['red','orange','green','orange','green','yellow']})
```

Expected result:

```
df1 =  pd.DataFrame({'type':['Apple3','Pear28','Banana0','Lime46'],'ind':['1','5','NaN','2'],'color':['orange','yellow','NaN','green']})
```

I appreciate all inputs, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need merge the two datasets and drop duplicates from the second one:

```
df1 = df1.merge(df2.reset_index().drop_duplicates(['type', 'color']), how='left')
print(df1)
```

Output:

```
      type  index   color
0   Apple3    1.0  orange
1   Pear28    5.0  yellow
2  Banana0    NaN     NaN
3   Lime46    2.0   green
```